# How to access data from differnt partial view after POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have 3 partialviews with 3 viewmodels on page:

1. List of accounts
2. Modal popup (you can modify multiple accounts here)
3. Search panel

I want to refresh 1. after doing POST on 2. This is straightforward, but what if I want to keep results I got after using Search Panel?

I can do this in 2 ways but both seems bad (correct me if I am wrong).

First (the one I chose and works) is to store viewmodel used in 3. in TempData. I do Search (POST) and save passed viewmodel in TempData. Then whenever I do POST on different partialview I can refresh 1. using data(search parametrs) from TempData.

```
 private const string SearchDataKey = "SearchData";
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult RefreshData()
    {
        if (TempData[SearchDataKey] != null)
            return PartialView("AccountListView", PrepareAccountListViewModelForSearchData(TempData[SearchDataKey] as AccountSearchViewModel));
        else
            return PartialView("AccountListView", PrepareAccountListViewModel());
    }
```

and saving ViewModel:

```
 public PartialViewResult Search(AccountSearchViewModel searchParameters)
    {
    ...
            TempData[SearchDataKey] = searchParameters;
            return PartialView("AccountListView", databaseAccountListViewModel);}
```

Second approach is to always POST "big" viewmodel with all 3 viewmodels. This way I will have data from Search's viewmodel but I will send many not needed information instead just Modal Popup's viewmodel which I need to call procedure.

I asked few MVC folks with better experience and they said they never had to store viewmodel in TempData but it still seems more reasonable than having 1 Big form and passing everything in every POST.

Do you know any better ways to handle this or which one is correct?

PS. Topic had "Best Practice" but was removed cause of warning message. I hope asking about opinion is still allowed on SO.

PS2. Most of my POSTs & GETs after initial load are through Ajax.

Comment: Asking for opinions are off-topic. And listen to your more experienced colleagues (run you app and hit F5 to refresh the browser to understand why you should not use `TempData` - its only lasts one request)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, In this particular case, F5 is not a problem cause I would prefer to load default data after that. Also if I choose 2nd approach and POST everything then I believe I will still lose data after F5 (since I will redirect to GET fallowing Post-redirect-get pattern) ? So to change question a bit, is there anything wrong in keeping 1 form per page and passing 1 big viewmodel(with partial views' viewmodels) in every POST

Answer (score 0):

> I do Search (POST)

This seems semantically incorrect to me. *Searching* is an action that shouldn't modify any state on the server. So using `GET` seems more appropriate. And when you use `GET` you have the benefit that all parameters are already present in the query string and thus preserved upon successive POST actions (like modifying an account in your case). So your `RefreshData` action could take the `AccountSearchViewModel` as parameter and the model binder will take care of the rest.

Comment: This makes total sense, but the problem is that I am using AJAX and refresh only partial views using JQuery, so only fragment of page is refreshed (thus I can't modify QueryString and the search data is not preserved). Apart from query strings, the only 2 methods (I know) to keep search data are to either send it in every POST or save in the TempData (both methods seems  questionable).